# how to create a thread to refresh data in 3 second interval

Tags: android

I need a thread (it does httppost ,and parse the answer xml and refresh listview to set the changes from parsed xml) in 3 sec interval

I have already tried this code

Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(

```
    new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            try {

                httpPostList(url);
                saxParseList();
                                    list.invalidateViews();

                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (Exception ie) {

            }

        }

    }, 1000, 1000 * 30);
```

Comment: Have you tried alarm manager?

Answer (score 1):

I would appreciate you to create a Service with an AsyncTask in it.
Async Tasks are the Android Synonym to normal Java Tasks, Documentation finding here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Services are Background Processes, seeing this Doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using handlers:

```
 Handler handler;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // ...
     handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            updateUI();
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                try {
                    sleep(3*1000); // 3 seconds
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }                       
        }
    };
    thread.start();
 }

 private synchronized void updateUI() {
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it using "Async task".